# Increment each field in a column by 1 - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to increment each field in a column by 1 starting from 2866. I've built the following query, but all it does is set each field to 2867 as opposed to 2868, 2869 etc...

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 2866
UPDATE view_kantech_matched SET image_id = @a + 1
WHERE image_id = null
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is there some column which currently indicates an ordering for these rows, such that we can readily identify *which* row should have the id 2866 assigned?

Comment: You should look at using ROW_NUMBER for this.

Comment: When you say "each field in a column" do you mean "each value in the column?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general structure for doing this would be:

```
;WITH Numbered as (
    SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <some column>) rn
    FROM view_kantech_matched
    WHERE image_id is NULL
)
UPDATE Numbered SET image_id = 2865 + rn
```

But I don't know what `<some column>` would be.

Comment: Thats great, thank you for this. I hadn't even heard of the WITH operator.

Comment: @SamFarr - it's called a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 2866
UPDATE view_kantech_matched SET image_id = @a, @a=@a + 1
WHERE image_id = null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you  want to update it to a value that starts at 2866 and increaments with every row you have to specify the column(s) to be used for the ordering.

Then you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH NoImageIDS AS
(
    SELECT vkm.*, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AnyColumn ASC)
    FROM dbo.view_kantech_matched vkm
    WHERE image_id IS NULL
)
UPDATE NoImageIDS SET image_id = RN + 2866
```